# Facing issues while using the update command on terminal

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, update-manager

I am not so familiar with Linux and I am still learning.
I am facing this issue whenever I run 'update' command on terminal.

[image: Screenshot of error encountered]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please copy text from terminal and post here instead of screenshot of terminal.

Comment: the ppa  was not made available to ubuntu 17.10 artful. remove the ppa and update again

Answer (score 1):

These messages mean that two of the PPAs you're using ([~vincent-c/cherrytree](https://launchpad.net/~vincent-c/+archive/ubuntu/cherrytree) and [~wiznote-team/ppa](https://launchpad.net/~wiznote-team/+archive/ubuntu/ppa)) aren't ready for 17.10 (`artful`).

I don't know, if they ever will be - the first one says it's deprecated and you should switch to [~giuspen/pa](https://launchpad.net/~giuspen/+archive/ubuntu/ppa).